# How to remove bold font in Chapter number and pages in toc when using report class?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, bold

I have found a number of similar questions and answers and tried them all, but none seem to be working for me.  I tried using the `tocloft` package and then `\renewcommand` for `\cftchapfont` and `\cftchappagefont` to change them to be `\normalfont` or `\mdseries` but still get them in bold font at the ToC. I tried a piece of code I found to redefine `\l@chapter` removing the `\bfseries` part but still get the Chapter number and the Chapter page on bold font.  My guess is that probably it has to do with the `report` class since most of what I found are for book and other classes.

If someone can help in this regard I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide an [Minimum working example, MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with \documentclass{...} including the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and ending with \end{document}.

Comment: `tocloft` is definitely the easiest way to go. Perhaps you can post a minimal document using `tocloft` to show what didn't work, and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, here is a MWE of what I have and the portions of my preamble that I think can be messing with the functioning of the tocloft package:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what you actually did, you appeared to have done the right thing.  Perhaps you forgot to remove the old `.aux` file?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, when trying to write a MWE I found that close to the end of my preamble I was re-redefining (yes, a second time) l@chapter for the appendix naming and numbering, and there the \bfseries was active changing it for all the Chapters in my toc.  Your answer actually works very well (if I remove that other part).